# Unable to generate Extent reports using version 4

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, extentreports

I'm using Extent report version 4,i've used same code mention in extent report java doc site but no lock and code is executed successfully but at last HTML report is not generating,any help will be appreciated.

Below is the Code:

```
import com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentReports;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentTest;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.reporter.ExtentAventReporter;
import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager;

public class Reporting {

    WebDriver driver;
    public static ExtentTest test;
    public static ExtentReports extent;

    public static void test() {

        // directory where output is to be printed
        ExtentAventReporter avent = new ExtentAventReporter(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "./reports/TestExecution.html");
        extent = new ExtentReports();
        extent.attachReporter(avent);
        test=extent.createTest("Login").assignAuthor("Rajesh");     

    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void after(){
        extent.flush();
    }



    @Test
    public void testings(){

        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();

        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        test();
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of
  `extent = new ExtentReports();`
use 
`extent = new ExtentReports(outputDirectory + File.separator + "ExtentReportsTestNG.html", true);`